# How to show a message with every single retry?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I've made a simple util method that return an Observable with a default configuration, the problem I have is in the retry, I want to show a message with every retry. This is mi code:

```
public static <T> Disposable getObservable(
            Context contexto,
            Observable<Response<T>> serviceObservable,
            Consumer<? super Response<T>> handleResponse,
            Consumer<? super Throwable> handleException
    ) {
        return serviceObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .retry((retryCount, throwable) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(contexto, "Retry..." + retryCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("TIMEOUT", "Retry..." + retryCount, throwable);

                    return retryCount < 3 && throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException;
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe(handleResponse, handleException);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, it does the retry but doesn't show the message.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: retry is calling after every  failure. so, u can try to make it on throwable  based to create toast

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, shows logs for me. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @michalbrz, I´ve realized that the log is a problem with my android studio, but the toast problem persist, it show the message in your test? Keep in mind that the class where is the method is a single class, and the context is passed from a fragment.

Comment: Try to move `observeOn` before `retry` so that `Toast` is called from the main/UI thread. Then it should work just fine

Comment: It works! Thank you @michalbrz